# Forcing 2.4GHz band on WiFi adapter

Tags: wifi-configuration

Even if I specify on the adapter "preferred band" 2.4GHz, the adapter try to connect to 5GHz, but due to the fact here signal is very weak, adapter continuously switches from 5 to 2.4, as a result connection is unstable.

- **OS**: Windows 11
- **Adapter**: Intel WiFi 6 AX201

Is there a way to fix the band I want to connect to?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek sorry, my mistake, I updated the question

Comment: Is there an option in advanced driver settings to use "802.11g only"?

Comment: The best solution (and ALWAYS recommended) is to have different SSIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, an easy way to specify the connection is with a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's free [WiFi Info View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/wifiinfoview/). The following shows how to do so in *WiFi Info View*.

[image: WiFi Info View]

To immediately change connection:

- Click a connection to select it, and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, *or*
- Right-click on the desired connection and select *Connect Selected Access Point*.

Since Windows sometimes forgets the previously used access point after hibernation, sleep or rebooting, create a desktop shortcut (which can also be assigned a keyboard shortcut) to return to the desired connection with just a key-press or mouse click:

- Right-click on the desired connection and select *Create Desktop Shortcut*.